# How to reference a pandas dataframe with an another dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in Python - `df_item` and `df_bill` shown as below:

```
df_item:

item_id   item_name
2         Noodles
3         Vegetables
4         Dairy Products
5         Ice Cream

df_bill:

bill_no   item_id
201       3
202       2
203       4
204       3
205       5
```

The `item_id` column in `df_item` sort of acts as a primary key of each row. How do I reference `df_item` within `df_bill` in such a way that `item_id` in `df_bill` is converted into `item_name`?

Expected Output:

```
df_bill:

bill_no  item_name
201      Vegetables
202      Noodles
203      Dairy Products
204      Vegetables
205      Ice Cream
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` but first remove column `item_id` by `drop` or `pop`:

```
s = df_bill['item_id'].map(df_item.set_index('item_id')['item_name'])
df = df_bill.drop('item_id', 1).assign(item_name = s)
```

Or:

```
s = df_bill.pop('item_id').map(df_item.set_index('item_id')['item_name'])
df = df_bill.assign(item_name = s)
```

---

```
print (df)
   bill_no       item_name
0      201      Vegetables
1      202         Noodles
2      203  Dairy Products
3      204      Vegetables
4      205       Ice Cream
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the two dataframes using the `item_id` column. For this you first need to set the indices correctly, reset it afterwards and remove the superflous column:

```
df_bill = df_bill.set_index("item_id")
df_item = df_item.set_index("item_id")
df = df_bill.join(df_item).reset_index()
df.drop(columns=["item_id"], inplace=True)
```

Or, as one chain of actions:

```
df = (df_bill.set_index("item_id")
             .join(df_item.set_index("item_id"))
             .reset_index()
             .drop(columns=["item_id"]))
```

Or, probably the easiest, using [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df_bill.merge(df_item).drop(columns=["item_id"])
```

All of them mess up the order of `bill_no`, though:

```
   bill_no       item_name
0      201      Vegetables
1      204      Vegetables
2      202         Noodles
3      203  Dairy Products
4      205       Ice Cream
```

However, you can always call `df.sort_values("bill_no")` to sort it again:

```
   bill_no       item_name
1      201      Vegetables
0      202         Noodles
3      203  Dairy Products
2      204      Vegetables
4      205       Ice Crea
```

Comment: Thanks! The merge function was amazing and the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

```
df_bill=df_bill.merge(df_item).drop('item_id',axis=1).sort_values('bill_no').set_index('bill_no')
```